# Firebase returns an object named differently each time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have this query:

```
const questionsRef = firebase
.database()
.ref('Works')
.orderByChild('firebaseKey')
.equalTo(this.props.match.params.id);
```

And it works, but in return I get this:

```
"-LDvDwsIrf_SCwSinpMa": { //!!!this is different for every object I get
    "answers": {
        "-LDvEEpkgbB9WFQDHuUZ": {
            "date": {...},
            "downloadURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/uczsieapp.appspot.com/o/images%2F483a1473-3056-4817-a495-9edb6589873e?alt=media&token=dae88bc8-fa39-4a36-97a4-7c9bbcb3898b",
            "firebaseKey": "-LDvEEpkgbB9WFQDHuUZ",
            "seen": true,
            "workKey": "-LDvDwsIrf_SCwSinpMa"
        }
    },
    "available": true,
    "boostAmount": 1,
    "category": "Historia",
    "createDate": {...},
    "creatorID": "tZS6bfXUujNXUAi6Rd0nPlmye693",
    "finishDate": {...},
    "firebaseKey": "-LDvDwsIrf_SCwSinpMa",
    "level": "Liceum",
    "number": 1,
    "photoURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/uczsieapp.appspot.com/o/images%2F365bfdd3-351f-4fb9-bca0-35890b2fc16d?alt=media&token=ed1f88bd-00ce-462a-b8eb-2fb4d2850142",
    "pointAmount": 32,
    "pointBoost": 64,
    "solverID": "tZS6bfXUujNXUAi6Rd0nPlmye693",
    "state": "Completed",
    "taskAmount": 4
},
```

And the thing is, this: `-LDvDwsIrf_SCwSinpMa` is the id. And every time it returns a different id. So how can I even automate it? Right now I'm getting it like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    // var key = ;
    const questionsRef = firebase.database().ref('Works').orderByChild('firebaseKey').equalTo(this.props.match.params.id);
    questionsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        let question = snapshot.val();
        console.log(question);
        let newState = {
            id: question.id,
            category: question.category,
            level: question.level,
            pointAmount: question.pointAmount,
            pointBoost: question.pointBoost,
            photoURL: question.photoURL,
        };
        console.log(newState);
        this.setState({
            question: newState
        });
    });
}
```

So how can I even get the information in the object, if it returns a different id every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`questionsRef` is Query (see [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query))

By calling `on()` on this query, you are "listening for data changes at the  "location" of the query. And the "callback will be triggered whenever the data changes", see the doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on). So if you are receiving a different object each time, it is because an object has been created under the node corresponding to your query (probably a new `answer`, with regards to the JSON you have published in your question).

So if what you want is to get the specific value of one node, you should use `once()`, which will "listen for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then stops listening". doc is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#once).

Note also that "even when there is only a single match for the query, the snapshot is a list". This means that you have to "loop over the result" like:

```
questionsRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    // ...
  });
});
```

See the detailed documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events

Answer (score 1):

If `questionsRef` is equal to

```
   {
       "-LDvDwsIrf_SCwSinpMa": {
           "answers": {},
           ......
      }
    }
```

`Object.keys(questionsRef)[0]` will be equal to `LDvDwsIrf_SCwSinpMa`